# Flutter Get Data From Friebase Realtime Database

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am a very simple human being. I need simple things in life. I just want to get a value as int/String/float from a **KNOWN not dynamic** child from realtime database, simple. no multiple values, no complex physics theory behind networking. I have seen tons of Stackoverflow on how to retrieve data into list, dynamic child, oh no. not me please. I just need a very simple single value from Database. I will show u the database structure below:
[Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUaoU.jpg)

I just need to get the value of "rewardAtEvery" as int. that's all nothing more, nothing less. I can live in peace afterward. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another human being here. These are the steps you can follow to achieve it:

1. Import the firebase realtime database dependence in your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
 ...
 firebase_database: ^4.1.1
```

2. import the package in your .dart file:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
```

3. Use it like this:

```
DataSnapshot snap =
      await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("path/to/Attributes/rewardAtEvery").once();

dynamic value = snap.value;
```

Comment: I can't Thanks enough my fellow human being enough. I just can't. The code is so simple yet so effective. Why not a single youtube video/ blog/ StackOverflow exist for it. I think I am so newbie and everyone else is an expert.